# Problema al aplicar DataTables a una tabla que se llenó con Ajax

Tags: ajax, datatables

Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema con aplicar DataTables en mi tabla, lo que pasa es que estoy llenando mi tabla con Ajax y la tabla se llena correctamente, también se aplica el DataTables, pero me sale un mensaje dentro de la tabla “No data available in tabe ” como si no trajera datos en la tabla. Les comparto mi código.

> Tabla HTML

```html
<div class="row">
            <!-- Column -->
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Artículos de la Venta</h4>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Add class <code>.table-hover</code></h6>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover" id="tabla_get_articulos_venta">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr id="tr_tablita">
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Código</th>
                                        <th>Producto</th>
                                        <th>Precio</th>
                                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        <th>Movimientos</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> Función para llenar tabla

```js
function get_articulos_venta(id_venta) {

            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Ventas_controller/get_articulos_venta')?>/"+id_venta,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {

                    var filas = data.length;
                    for (  i = 0 ; i < filas; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                        var nuevafila = "<tr><td>" +
                        contador + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].codigo + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].descripcion + "</td><td>" +
                        "$ "+data[i].precioCompra + "</td><td>" +
                        data[i].cantidad + "</td><td>"+
                        data[i].preciototal + "</td><td>"+
                        "<a type='button' onclick='delete_articulo_venta("+data[i].ideDetalleVenta+")' class='btn btn-danger'>" +
                            "<i class='fa fa-times'></i>" +
                        "</a> " +
                        "<a type='button' onclick='get_info_articulo_venta("+data[i].ideDetalleVenta+")'  class='btn btn-warning'>" +
                            "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>" +
                        "</a>" +"</td></tr>" ;

                        $("#tabla_get_articulos_venta").append(nuevafila);
                        contador++;
                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error");
   
                }
            });
        }
```

> Resultado
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se ve que se llena la tabla y se aplica el diseño de DataTables, pero dentro de la tabla me sale el mensaje “La tabla no trae datos” y si exporto el Excel o el PDF la tabla me sale vacía.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Lo que sucede es que `DataTable()` maneja importando los datos, y como no tuviste nada, es que `Datatable()` no lo tiene en memoria

El detalle es que ejecutas el `DataTable()` antes de llenar la table, y una vez que ya se ejecutó estas chancando tu misma tabla.

lo que puedes hacer es `ejecutar DataTable()` despues del `for en el AJAX` o puedes aumentar ya a los generados de esta manera

```
$('#tbl_entidad').dataTable( {
    data : jsonObject,

    columns: [
              {"data" : "id"},
              {"data" : "name"},
              {"data" : "cif"}             
              ],

});
```

Comment: Ya lo hice tanto antes y después de haber llamado a mi función que llena la tabla y de ninguna de las dos formas me queda.